# Graph edit framework

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, vector-graphics

I was looking at [MeVisLab](http://www.mevislab.de/) and I wondered if anyone knows a good framework for making a user interface similar to the one they use. I like the designing flow with boxes and arrows thing.

What I would really like is to able to integrate with C++ using Qt, and perhaps export the graph to xml of something like that.

There is another example of the interface here:

[image]

I hope someone knows something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt's Graphics View is a "framework" which does a good bit of the handling for the kind of scenario you describe.  It doesn't take much code to get off the ground and within striking range of what you're looking for:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview-diagramscene.html

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview-elasticnodes.html

I'm not aware of any open-source Qt-based programs that offer *exactly* what you want already written.  Just noticed IBM did open source "DataExplorer", which is interesting to me...I might go take a look at that myself:

http://www.research.ibm.com/dx/

Comment: you are absolutely right! I was just wondering if there was something with some graph features. optimizing layout of planar graphs and stuff like that..

Comment: It's a field of study, lots of approaches.  For starters look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing